# Propositional Logic: Conditional Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm learning how to prove statements using the rules of inference, and now I'm stuck in this problem where I have to use the conditional proof to prove it.
It says: $P\to (Q \lor R)$, $S \to ¬Q ⇒ (P \land S) \to R$

So, we want to prove $(P \land S) \to  R$

If anyone could explain this it would be very helpful!
Thanks!

So far this is what I got but I feel it's the wrong approach...

1. P∧S
2. P
3. $P\to (Q \lor R)$
4. Q∨R

Comment: Isn’t it clear that if Q is false, and (Q or R) is true, then R must be true?

Comment: @Jneven : Your edit completely changed the question. It is now nonsensical.

Comment: Please quote the exact statement of the problem with your ideas for approaching/solving it.

Comment: Your start is right, but you have to add to each step the comment regarding the rule applied: 1) Assumption, 2) Simplification, 3) Premise, 4) Modus Ponens with 2 and 3.